# Skip repeating array and reverse order of the array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-reverse

I have this array. In this I want to skip the value for reverse data.

```
$data = array(
    array(2, 1),
    array(1, 2),
    array(1, 2),
    array(2, 1),
    array(2, 3),
    array(3, 2),
    array(4, 5)
);
```

I want to skip the values:

```
array(1,2)
array(1,2)
array(2,1)
array(3,2)
```

And I want the result array to be like this:

```
array(
    array(2, 1),
    array(2, 3),
    array(4, 5)
);
```

Comment: You mean you want to eliminate duplicate values, and then sort the array? Or you you mean simply remove individual values from the array? Can you explain what you mean by "skip" and what rules determine what elements are to be skipped?

Comment: Yes, I want to eliminate the duplicate value as well as eliminate the reverse order of the array.

Comment: He wants to delete the duplicate sub-arrays, even if the elements in the sub-array are in a different order. Basically unique sub-arrays - keys not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = [[2,1], [1,2], [1,2], [2,1], [2,3], [3,2], [4,5]];

$data = array_map(
    function($value) {
        sort($value);
        return serialize($value);
    },
    $data
);

$data = array_unique($data);
$data = array_map('unserialize', $data);
array_walk($data, 'sort');

var_dump($data);
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/61PNm)

**EDIT**

As per arbogast's comment, this can be simplified even further, eliminating the serialize/unserialize steps:

```
$data = [[2,1], [1,2], [1,2], [2,1], [2,3], [3,2], [4,5]];

array_walk($data, 'sort');
$data = array_unique($data, SORT_REGULAR);

var_dump($data);
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/A1gkX)

Comment: This does sort the sub-arrays though so not 100%.

Comment: Well you could always skip that last line `array_walk($data, 'sort');` if you didn't want to sort the subarrays

Comment: You can have same result if you use array_unique($data, SORT_REGULAR); then you don't have to use serialization.

Comment: @arbogast - thanks for the tip, I wasn't aware of that flag for `array_unique()`.... useful to know

Comment: @Mark Baker Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function filterArray($data)
{
      $result = array();
      array_push($result, $data[0]); //You can always add first item without performing any check
      for($i=1; $i<count($data); $i++)
      {
          $allowAdd = true;
          foreach($result as $res)
          {
              if(($res == $data[$i]) || ($res[0] = $data[$i][1] && $res[1] = $data[$i][0]))
              {
                  $allowAdd = false;
                  break;
              }
          }
          if($allowAdd)
            array_push($result, $data[$i]);
     }
     return $result;
}
```

Now, when you call `filterArray($data)`, this will return you the filtered result.